# move_uploaded_file php function is not working

Tags: php, file-upload, image-upload

I know very well that similar questions are answered many times in this site. I google and search many forum bt I can't solve the problem.

`move_uploaded_file` function is not working, this function cannot upload the file due to appropriate path.

Here is my code

```
$targetPath = "/home/abc/public_html/uploads/";

        let my website is abc.com

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],$targetPath.$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
```

- I have to upload file in `/public_html/uploads/downloads`
- `move_uploaded_file` function is in `/public_html/assets/uploadify`
- input form is in
  `/public_html/application/modules/downloads/views/admin` location

**NOTE:** This code is working fine in my localhost

can anybody suggest for path

Plz dnt mark dublicate

Comment: Have you tried putting the full path to the directory? Where is `public_html` located? Chances are you need the full server path to that directory - e.g. `/var/www/public_html`

Comment: Have you checked file permissions?

Comment: yes, i gave `downloads` folder 0777 permission

Comment: `$targetPath = "../../../../../uploads/"; `  try this directory.

Comment: @JeesKDenny No, same result

Comment: where the entire site code situated in the server? please give us the directory.

Comment: inside  `home/abc/public_html/` LET my website is abc.com

Comment: i am using CI framework, and code was written 3 years ago. Is this responsible for this problem

Comment: @JeesKDenny, fyi,  if you use `$targetPath =  __DIR__ ."/../../../../../uploads/";` then it will **always** be relative to the current PHP script as it is an absolute file path. i.e. the 'current working directory' settings will never be used. Note, the filepath always statrts with a '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your upload file is in the public_html directory, change the $targetPath to `/uploads/` and change

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],"$targetPath".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: add quotes to `$targetPath`

Comment: i directly use "/uploads/".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']

Comment: Also, check that you have used the correct `<input type="file" name="Filedata" >`

Comment: Alternatively, if none of that works, use `http://example.com/uploads/"`

Comment: my coding is working in local, and next I tried as u said `http://example.com/uploads/`